# ECS Task definition App Mesh Virtual node name does not get set through console

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-app-mesh

I am creating a task definition that uses App Mesh. I am trying to set the Virtual name using the console.

The UI clearly shows that I can select the virtual node name.

[image: setting virtual node name]

However, after I create the new revision, if I create a revision off of that, I see that the virtual node name has blanked out.

[image: missing virtual node example]

This is problematic as my container does not pass ELB health checks since the sidecar isn’t behaving properly.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, for some reason hitting `Create` does not apply the virtual node name change.

Once you manually hit apply, the problem goes away.

[image: apply button]